# COM+ with JAVA in eclipse

Tags: java, com+

I want to know if that has to do with a code made ​​in JAVA visit a class available in COM +?

Answer (score 3):

There are many libraries that bridge COM and Java.  Here just few

1. [JACOB (free)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/)
2. [JavaComBridge (commerical)](http://javacombridge.com/)
3. [Com4J (free)](http://com4j.kohsuke.org/tutorial.html)

There are many more out there,  just google for them.

Comment: how i do to install JACOB (free), because i have try but i could not install?

Comment: Read here http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/jacob-project/index.php?title=Main_Page